# How can I make a collection which behaves like the Session[] collection? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I desperately need to mirror the behaviour of the Session collection in ASP.NET (in terms of it's behaviour when you retrieve items).  I've spent a long time on this but have so far got nowhere.

A session is like a Dictionary except that if you access a Session and the value doesn't exist, you get `null` rather than it throwing an exception. This is all I need to duplicate.

I tried overriding the indexer to add a null check but it throws a stack overflow exception:

```
public class CriteriaCollection : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    private object GetData(string key)
    {
        object value = null;
        if (this.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            value = this[key];
        }
        return value;
    }

    private void SetData(string key, object value)
    {
        this[key] = value;
    }

    public new object this[string key]
    {
        get { return GetData(key); }
        set { SetData(key, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Silvermind - No I can't as the values can only be strings in a NameValueCollection. I need other types (eg int).

Comment: @Silvermind but that allows duplicate keys - which isn't ideal.

Comment: Ok, I removed my comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have created your own indexer, you want to call the old indexer in your own code.

Replace `this[key]` by `base[key]` in your code.

Comment: Should I also use base.ContainsKey?  Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: @NickG `ContainsKey` should work fine, you did not override it or create a new version, so the `this` and `base` versions are the same.